# Congruences between Eisenstein series and cusp forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, modular-representation-theory

Let $k\geq 4$ be an even integer. Let $p>k$ be a prime
such that $p\mid B_k$, the $k$th Bernoulli number. Then there is a primitive cusp form $f=\sum_{n\geq1}c(n, f)q^n$
of weight $k$ and level $1$ and a prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $K_f$, the field of coefficients of $f$, lying over $p$ such that
$c(n, f) =\sigma_{k}(n) \pmod{\mathfrak{P}}$ for all $n\geq 1$.

This results can be seeing as the starting point of Ribet's proof of the converse of Herbrand's theorem on the $p$-class group of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$.

Is this result true for any level? Otherwise, is there any special cases where this is true for some level $N$?

I add here a precise question I am interested in:

Let $k$ be an integer and let $G=a_{0}+\sum_{n\geq1}a_{n}q^n$ be of weight $k$ and level $N>1$ (primitive), with $a_{0}\neq0$ a rational and $a_{n}$, for $n\geq1$, an integer. Assume that $G$ is an eigenform and let $p$ be an odd prime such that $a_{0}\equiv0\pmod{p}$. Let me consider an example that interests me: Let $D>0$ be a fundamental discriminant and $k$ even, $$G_{k,D}(\tau)=\frac{1}{2}L(1-k,(\frac{D}{\cdot}))+\sum_{n\geq1}\left(\sum_{d\mid n}(\frac{D}{d})d^{k-1}\right)q^n,$$ for $k=12$, $D=8$ and $p=13$ we have the required assumptions for $G_{k,D}$.

The modular form $G$ behaive like a cuspform modulo $p$. My question, is there a primitive cuspform $f=\sum_{n\geq1}c_{n}q^n$ such that $a_{n}\equiv c_{n}\pmod{\mathfrak{P}}$ which is of level $N'$ (not necessary $N$)?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A cusp form of level 1 is also of level N. Do you mean a newform ?

Comment: @HenriCohen The question states "primitive" so I think you can interpret this as a question about newforms.

Comment: What kind of result are you hoping for? The result you quote is a congruence between a level 1 Eisenstein series and a level 1 cusp form. For general N, do you want a congruence between a level 1 Eis series and a cusp form that is primitive of level N, or do you want both the Eisenstein series and the cusp form to be primitive of level N?

Comment: Interpreted literally, this cannot be true: congruences between modular forms of different levels (here an Eisenstein series of level $1$ with an eigencuspform of level $N>1$) will not be congruences for *all* $n≥1$ (the congruence will not hold for primes $\ell$ dividing $N$). With that restriction in mind, the answer is yes.